# Disabling the ability to scroll by clicking the blank space on a scroll bar

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I am writing a small swing application and I am trying to essentially get the scroll bar down to just the up and down buttons. I have already spent hours learning that the little clicky thing is in fact called a thumb, and with that took 40 seconds to figure out how to disable it. Here's my next challenge though: I want to disable the users ability to scroll the JScrollPane by clicking on the blank space in the scroll bar between the 2 buttons.

Does anyone know of a method to do this (or a method to overwrite to stop this)?

For the curious, disabling the thumb:

```
JTabel tabel = new JTabel(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table)
JScrollBar scrollBar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
BasicScrollBarUI barUI = new BasicScrollBarUI() {
protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c,Rectangle thumbBounds) {}};
scrollBar.setUI(barUI);
```

Comment: Sounds almost easier to replace the scroll bar all together with a panel and two buttons :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer easier is for sissies!

Comment: It takes real intelligence to take a simple task and make it complicate, welcome to my club, I'm the president ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setBlockIncrement(0);
```

I'm curious, how did you disable the thumb?